# Class Boundaries Definition of discrete Data

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

why do we add and subtract 0.5 due to the definition . What is reason for this?
One of the definitions can be found here:
http://tistats.com/definitions/class-boundaries/
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the claim is *not* that the data is discrete, but that the class labels are discrete.  At your link, the answer to your question is "while preventing gaps" -- every possible value of the data ends up assigned to a class.  (Sometimes you don't know that your real-world data is precisely discrete, approximately discrete, or continuous.  It would be comforting to know that, regardless of which of those occurs, your process assigns a class to every possible data value.)

Say my two classes are "$1$" and "$2$" but my variable, $x$ can take any value in $[0,3]$.  Suppose I make a measurement and find $x = 0.1$.  Pretty clearly, this should go in the class "$1$".  (I put classes in quotation marks because they are *labels* for ranges of values.)  But what about values between $1$ and $2$?  We have to put a boundary somewhere to divide values belonging to the class "$1$" and values belonging to the class "$2$".  In the absence of any other reason, why not but the boundary halfway from $1$ to $2$.  Then values in the interval $[0,1.5)$ are assigned to the class "$1$" and values in the interval $(1.5,3]$ are assigned to the class "$2$".

What about the value $1.5$?  There are two standard ways to deal with it

- Method 1:  On the one hand, the probability of a continuous variable having the value $1.5$ exactly is zero, so we need not concern ourselves with this eventuality.
- Method 2:  ... Well, if that's true assign it to either class, since the probability of that choice affecting the assignment of a value is zero (by the argument used in method 1).

So just pick whichever class and attach $1.5$ to its interval.

Comment: thank you Eric. My question is:  what for?
Why don't we do the same for the continuous variables?
Thank you

Comment: @Eu2718 : We do.  This is the automatic thing to do for continuous variables.  The problem is not the variables, the problem is the discrete labels.  If the labels are "0-99" and "100-199", where do we put the values in the interval (99,100)?  This is only a difficulty if we *believe* the labels and convince ourselves there cannot be data "in the gap".